# WooCommerce get stock from a different database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, stock

### My problem:

One of my clients has a webshop and he uses the same storehouse as another webshop in Czechia.
The current stock on both webshops should be synced automatically.
So my idea was to tell WooCommerce to get the stock not from my own database but from the one in Czechia.

My problem is that I couldn't find the file in WooCommerce where I can change the databases.
I read something about a stock.php in the "single-product" folder but in the newest WooCommerce-folder, there isn't a file named like this.

Comment: Could you create an api system on webshop in Czechia that give you real stock of product. After you have to create a script or plugin that read those api and made a sync.

Comment: I don't know if there's the possibility to create an API on the Czechian-server - but I will ask the Czechian company if they can do that..

but I need a hook into woocommerce to sync the stock and "override" the one out of my own database - ore am I wrong?

Comment: i found a file in woocommerce called `abstract-wc-product.php` - [link](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php) 
stupid question - but do you have any tips how i can change the database in this file?

Comment: I don't have idea. Generally is not suggested to edit plugin file core, because any update maybe delete all you can edit.

Comment: okay, yes i already read about that problem..

so i have to write a new plugin in which i filter the stock of woocommerce..

could i do that with this example:
`// define the woocommerce_get_stock_quantity callback 
function filter_woocommerce_get_stock_quantity( $var, $instance ) { 
    // make filter magic happen here... 
    return $var; 
}; 
         
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_stock_quantity', 'filter_woocommerce_get_stock_quantity', 10, 2 );`

?

Comment: I saw the code oon [this page](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_get_stock_quantity/)